# Python on Pi 3 to open and control a console application

Tags: python, linux, automation

I have a very simple problem but cant seem to get a simple solution anywhere. 
I have an application running on my Pi which I start by typing into terminal and passing some arguments. For example:

```
sudo $HOME/Projects/myExampleApp MD_DWNC2378
```

This results in the console application starting and as expected, can take keyboard inputs.

Now, what I want to do is repeat the process described so far from a python application. My python application should be able to open the myExampleApp in terminal, get a reference to the console window and then direct any commands from my Python application as a keyboard press to myExampleApp.

On a windows platform, pywinauto library does the job.

What is the best option for doing what I described on linux running on my Pi 3?

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Look at the python `subprocess` module.

Comment: pywinauto is for GUI apps, why using it for console??? +1 for `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html for receiving commands. Your application can be run with subprocess as suggested by another user:

```
import cmd
import sys
import subprocess
class Controller(cmd.Cmd):
    cmd = 'while true; do cat /dev/stdin;sleep 1;done'
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    def default(self, cmd):
        self.p.stdin.write(cmd+"\n")
        a=self.p.stdout.readline()
        sys.stdout.write("subprocess returned {}".format(a))
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Controller().cmdloop()
    except:
        print('Exit')
```

Running this script will present you with a CLI interface. Any command sent in will be forwarded to the stdin of your application (simulated by the shell script shown).

If you don't need to process the returning stdout you can skip the `self.p.stdout.readline()` call. If you need the returning data, it may be beneficial to change the readline() call to read(), this will read until the application sends an EOF.

The sudo requirement of your application can probably be overcome by running the python script with sudo. I'm no security expert, but be aware of the security risks of running the script as sudo, as well as the shell=True parameter of the `Popen` call.